# Specify robots.txt using IIS for different sub-domains

Tags: asp.net, iis, robots.txt

I have a site at say www.example.com and also have two staging platforms at beta.example.com and preview.example.com and I need a way to set different robots.txt for each using IIS or something similar

The reason for this is that I want to disallow spiders on all but the www domain as they are spidering duplicated content

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just have 3 different robots.txt files, one for each host?

If you need to handle this automatically, I would suggest a `HTTPHandler` that handles requests for robots.txt.  If the `Request.Url.Host` is www.example.com, return robots.allow.txt, if not, return robots.deny.txt.

If you are interested in this idea and need some example code to get you started, let me know.

Comment: Thanks pseudocoder, I think the httphandler would be the way to go. Can't / rather not have 3 as it is all published from a build script that was written by someone else - not sure of the ins and outs of it so I'm happy to leave it alone